# php artisan make:component not exist after upgrade from Laravel 6 to Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-components

i have upgraded from laravel 6 to 7 then 8 then 9 and make:component command not exist how to update it ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if you have `laravel/ui` installed?

Comment: is it related to Laravel blade component ?